# Does RTDB query reduce bandwidth?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of users, assume 10k. 
Now if I run a query like below:

```
query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
                .orderByChild(SELECTED_QUERY)
                .limitToFirst(150);
```

Will it consume bandwidth of `150 users' data` or `10k users' data`? 
This question may be silly, but I haven't found expected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the SDK retrieves all `users` or just the first 150 depends on whether you've [defined an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) on `SELECTED_QUERY`. Without an index the SDK will retrieve all of `users` and filter locally on the client; *with* the index the filtering will happen on the server.

Given your comment, you'll need to add an index to your rules like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "users": {
      ...
      ".indexOn": "name"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Assume `SELECTED_QUERY = "name" `,  where `name` is a child of a single user. And I haven't added `.indexOn` in rtdb rules. If I run above query, will it load all users data locally ? i.e. consume bandwidth of all `10k users`?

Comment: Without an index the SDK will retrieve all of users and filter locally on the client.

Comment: Without `.indexOn` in rules, it will consume bandwidth of 10k users?
But if I just add `.indexOn` in rules, then it will reduce to 150 users?
Am I right?

Comment: **Without** an index the SDK will retrieve the entire `users` node and filter locally on the client; **with** the index the filtering will happen on the server and only child nodes that match the query are transferred to the client.

Comment: I just want to be clear. if I just add .indexOn in rules, then bandwidth will reduce to 150 users? Am I right? Please answer in `yes` or `no`.

Comment: Yes, when properly implemented the SDK will only retrieve the 150 matching nodes from the server. But unless I can see exactly what you do, I can't give that type of blanket "yes" or "no" response, which is why I explain how the system works, and have updated my answer to show what you need to do in your rules once you gave enough information to allow that. --- I recommend implementing the index and checking of the usage chart in the Firebase console goes down after that.